# Modifying captured parameters in nested lambda: gcc vs clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, c++17

I come across a weird behavior when switching from `clang` to `gcc`. `clang` successfully compiles the code while `gcc` reports an error. Here is a minimal example to reproduce the behavior. I have tried this with `c++14` and `c++17` with multiple `clang` and `gcc` versions.

Who is right here, clang or gcc?

```
struct A {
  int value;
};

auto makeCallback(const A& a) {
    auto callback = [aCopy = a](int i) {
    [aCopy, i]() mutable { aCopy.value = i; }();
  };
return callback;
}
```

Edit:
Changing the outer lambda to be `mutable`, resolves the issue on `gcc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`clang` is right. The inner closure captures `aCopy` by value, and mutating that doesn't affect the outer closure. `gcc` seems to get confused by the identical name for the variable in question. You can work around this by giving it another name. Example:

```
auto callback = [aCopy = a](int i) {
  [anotherName = aCopy, i]() mutable { anotherName.value = i; }();
};
```

This compiles with both `clang` and `gcc`.